# Chrome doesn't display Javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

System: Windows Server 2012 via Parallel's 11

I'm experiencing a strange problem on Google Chrome 53.0.2 with the Javascript alert box.

As you know, when the alert() function is fired in the browser, a dialog box will immediately be displayed in the browser window. Strangely, in my Chrome browser, the alert box does not appear until after I click the mouse.

For example: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81t3a53f/) should show an alert dialog immediately after I click the button. And, in fact, it works fine in my Firefox and IE browsers. However, the alert dialog does not popup in my Chrome browser until after I click my mouse. In other words, when I click the button nothing happens, but if I click my mouse (anywhere), the alert dialog is displayed.

This is the markup for the above fiddle:

```
<button onclick="alert()">
Show alert dialog
</button>
```

In an attempt to fix the problem, I uninstalled Chrome (as well as all the Google folders that are created in the Registry, Programs x86, AppData, etc.) - Also, I have disabled all my Chrome extensions and have tried using Incognito. None of the above has fixed the problem.

What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m and this works as expected for me.

Comment: There seems to be plenty of problems using Chrome when Windows is hosted by the Parallels VM software. My $2 bet says the problem lies in Parallels. Refer here for another strange chrome on windows under Parallels or VMWare bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue in recent weeks.
After much testing I was able to correct this by the following means

1. Settings> Show advanced settings
2. Scroll to bottom
3. Remove the checkmark from "use hardware acceleration when available"

I won't pretend to know why this worked.